# WM_DESTROY message not being received by WndProc in x64 Windows Assembly Program

Tags: winapi, masm, masm64

I'm trying to recreate using MASM /w Visual Studio 2019 something similar to the following C++ code which works. Essentially at this stage just want the window to be movable and the close button to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM
    lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t windowclass[] = L"MyWinTest";

    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = 0;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = NULL;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = windowclass;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    
    RegisterClassExW(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW(
        0, 
        windowclass,
        L"MyWindow",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        800, 
        600, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        hInstance, 
        NULL);

        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

}
```

In my version of x64 assembly using MASM the Window is created and displayed, also WndProc is being hit, can see it get message WM_CREATE and WM_PAINT but the Window can't be moved and can't be closed. I did compile the C++ version as x64 and output assembly listing for comparison, but it looks very similar as far as I can tell to the assembly version.

```
WSTR MACRO lbl:req,qstr:VARARG
LOCAL arg,unq,qot,q
    lbl LABEL WORD
    FOR arg,<qstr>
        qot SubStr <arg>,1,1
        q = 0
        IFIDNI qot,<!'>;'
            q = 1
        ELSEIFIDNI qot,<!">;"
            q = 1
        ELSE
            DW arg
        ENDIF
        IF q EQ 1
            unq SubStr <arg>,2,@SizeStr(<arg>)-2
        %   FORC c,<unq>
                DW "&c"
            ENDM
        ENDIF
    ENDM
    DW 0
ENDM

L MACRO qstr:VARARG
LOCAL sym,seg
    seg EQU <.code>
    %IFIDNI <@CurSeg>,<_DATA>
        seg EQU <.data>
    ENDIF
    .CONST
        ALIGN 4
        WSTR sym,qstr
    seg
    EXITM <OFFSET sym>
ENDM

extrn   LoadCursorW: PROC
extrn   MessageBoxW: PROC
extrn   ExitProcess: PROC
extrn   GetModuleHandleW: PROC
extrn   RegisterClassExW: PROC
extrn   CreateWindowExW: PROC
extrn   GetLastError: PROC
extrn   DefWindowProcW: PROC
extrn   ShowWindow: PROC
extrn   Sleep: PROC
extrn   GetMessageW: PROC
extrn   TranslateMessage: PROC
extrn   DispatchMessageW: PROC
extrn   DestroyWindow: PROC
extrn   UpdateWindow: PROC
extrn   PostQuitMessage: PROC
extrn   BeginPaint: PROC
extrn   EndPaint: PROC
.data
wstr windowClassName,"AsmTestClass",0,0
wstr windowTitle,"AsmTest",0,0

HWND_DESKTOP        textequ <0h>
MB_OK           textequ <0h>

INFINITE            textequ <0ffffffffh>
WM_CREATE       textequ <0001h>
WM_DESTROY      textequ <0002h>
WM_SIZE         textequ <0005h>
WM_PAINT        textequ <000fh>
WM_CLOSE            textequ <0010h>
WM_QUIT         textequ <0012h>
SW_HIDE         textequ <0000h>
SW_SHOW         textequ <0005h>

CS_VREDRAW      textequ <0001h>
CS_HREDRAW      textequ <0002h>

WS_OVERLAPPED   textequ <00000000h>
WS_CAPTION      textequ <00c00000h>
WS_SYSMENU      textequ <00080000h>
WS_MINIMIZEBOX  textequ <00020000h>

CW_USEDEFAULT   textequ <80000000h>

IDI_APPLICATION textequ <00007f00h>

WINDOW_WIDTH        DWORD   800
WINDOW_HEIGHT   DWORD   600

WNDCLASSEX STRUCT DWORD
    cbSize          DWORD   ?
    style           DWORD   ?
    lpfnWndProc     QWORD   ?
    cbClsExtra      DWORD   ?
    cbWndExtra      DWORD   ?
    hInstance       QWORD   ?
    hIcon           QWORD   ?
    hCursor         QWORD   ?
    hbrBackground   QWORD   ?
    lpszMenuName    QWORD   ?
    lpszClassName   QWORD   ?
    hIconSm         QWORD   ?
WNDCLASSEX ENDS

MSG STRUCT 
    hwnd                QWORD   ?
    message         DWORD   ?
    wParam          QWORD   ?
    lParam          QWORD   ?
    time                DWORD   ?
    x               DWORD   ?
    y               DWORD   ?
MSG ENDS

PAINTSTRUCT STRUCT 8
    hdc             QWORD   ?
    fErase          DWORD   ?
    left                DWORD   ?
    top             DWORD   ?
    right           DWORD   ?
    bottom          DWORD   ?
    fRestore            DWORD   ?
    fIncUpdate      DWORD   ?
    rgbReserved     BYTE        32 DUP (?)
PAINTSTRUCT ENDS

.code
main proc

LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX
LOCAL hWnd:QWORD
LOCAL hInstance:QWORD
LOCAL hCursor:QWORD
LOCAL ATOM:WORD
LOCAL message:MSG
    
    sub     rsp, 8

    ; hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL)
    mov     rcx, 0
    call        GetModuleHandleW
    mov     hInstance, rax

    ; hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION)
    mov     edx, IDI_APPLICATION
    xor     ecx, ecx
    call        LoadCursorW
    mov     hCursor, rax
  
    ; Setup Window Class
    mov     wc.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX
    mov     wc.style, CS_VREDRAW or CS_HREDRAW
    lea     rax, OFFSET WndProc
    mov     wc.lpfnWndProc, rax
    mov     wc.cbClsExtra, 0
    mov     wc.cbWndExtra, 0
    lea     rax, hInstance
    mov     wc.hInstance, rax
    mov     wc.hbrBackground, 0
    mov     wc.lpszMenuName, 0
    lea     rax, hCursor
    mov     wc.hCursor, rax
    lea     rax, windowClassName
    mov     wc.lpszClassName, rax
    mov     wc.hIconSm, 0
    lea     rcx, wc
    call        RegisterClassExW
    mov     ATOM, ax

    ; CreateWindowExW
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+88], 0               ;   lpParam
    lea     rax, hInstance
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+80], rax             ;   hInstance
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+72], 0               ;   hMenu
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+64], 0               ;   hWndParent
    mov     edx, WINDOW_HEIGHT
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+56], edx             ;   nHeight
    mov     edx, WINDOW_WIDTH
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+48], edx             ;   nWidth
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+40], CW_USEDEFAULT   ;   Y
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+32], CW_USEDEFAULT   ;   X
    mov     r9d, WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_CAPTION or WS_SYSMENU or WS_MINIMIZEBOX        ; dwStyle
    lea     r8, windowTitle                     ;   lpWindowName
    lea     rdx, windowClassName                    ;   lpClassName
    xor     ecx,ecx                             ;   dwExStyle
    call        CreateWindowExW

    cmp     rax,  0
    je      WindowFailed
    jmp     WindowSuccess

WindowFailed:
    call        GetLastError
    ; to-do check error ?

WindowSuccess:
    mov     hWnd, rax

    mov     rcx, hWnd       ; hWnd
    mov     edx, SW_SHOW        ; nCmdShow
    call        ShowWindow

    mov     rcx, hWnd       ; hWnd
    call        UpdateWindow

MessageLoop:
    xor     r9d, r9d            ; wMsgFilterMax
    xor     r8d, r8d            ; wMsgFilterMin
    xor     edx, edx            ; hWnd
    lea     rcx, message        ; lpMsg
    call        GetMessageW

    test        eax, eax
    je      QuitMessageLoop

    lea     rcx, message            ; lpMsg
    call    TranslateMessage

    lea     rcx, message            ; lpMsg
    call        DispatchMessageW
       
    jmp     MessageLoop 

QuitMessageLoop: 
    mov     ecx, eax                            ; uExitCode
    call        ExitProcess

main endp

WndProc proc
    LOCAL hWnd:QWORD
    LOCAL uMsg:DWORD
    LOCAL wParam:QWORD
    LOCAL lParam:QWORD
    LOCAL result:QWORD
    LOCAL ps:PAINTSTRUCT
    LOCAL hdc:QWORD

    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     lParam, r9
    mov     wParam, r8
    mov     uMsg, edx
    mov     hWnd, rcx
    
    ; msg handler
    cmp     uMsg,WM_CREATE
    je      create
    cmp     uMsg,WM_PAINT
    je      paint   
    cmp     uMsg,WM_DESTROY
    je      destroy

    ; default
    mov     r9, lParam
    mov     r8, wParam
    mov     edx, uMsg
    mov     rcx, hWnd
    call        DefWindowProcW
    mov     result,rax
    jmp     finish

create:
    mov     result, 0
    jmp     finish

paint:
    mov     rcx, hWnd
    lea     rdx, ps
    call        BeginPaint
    mov     hdc, rax

    ; to-do HDC paint stuff here

    mov     rcx, hWnd
    lea     rdx, ps
    call        EndPaint

    mov     result, 0
    jmp     finish

destroy:
    xor     ecx, ecx            ; nExitCode
    call        PostQuitMessage
    mov     result, 0
    jmp     finish

finish: 
    mov     rax, result
    
    ret 

WndProc endp
End
```

Note due to local statement masm is automatically adding to my main before the sub rsp,8: (-152 + -8 = -160 )

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
add     rsp, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFF68h
```

and adding to wndproc routine (-120 + -8  = -128)

```
    push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
add     rsp, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFF88h

...

leave
```

Comment: you need not `sub     rsp, 8` but `sub     rsp, 40` (for preserve 32 (4*8) space for callee)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

error in code - in both procs -

`sub rsp, 8`

when from [x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170)

> *The caller is responsible for allocating space for the callee's parameters. The caller must always allocate sufficient space to store
> four register parameters, even if the callee doesn't take that many
> parameters.*

so need - to store four register parameters - 4*8 and +8 for 16-byte align, so

```
sub rsp, 40
```

in concrete case calls to `DispatchMessageW` and `TranslateMessage` can corrupt (overwrite) `message` because it located in callee's parameters space. if test under debugger - i view that `DispatchMessageW` overwrite `message` in prolog and than already use wrong `message`

Comment: Ok I'll double check this, although masm is adding this due to local statements, i only added sub rsp,8 for 16-byte align in addition to what masm was adding. i'll add the disassembly for that as well

Comment: @MalcolmMcCaffery - masm only allocate stack for local vars but not for callee. i not simply paste this answer but check your code. error exactly in `DispatchMessageW`. set bp on this call. look for `message` before and after call.